# Rewriting SQL Server query with multiple UNIONs

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, unpivot

Is there a better (more efficient) way to write this query? It seems like there should be a way to write it with only one `UNION`.

Query:

```
SELECT 'Value1' as PropertyKey, PropertyValue=(SELECT Value1 FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK))
UNION
SELECT 'Value2' as PropertyKey, PropertyValue=(SELECT Value2 FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK))
UNION
SELECT 'Value3' as PropertyKey, PropertyValue=(SELECT Value3 FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK))
UNION
...
SELECT 'Value100' as PropertyKey, PropertyValue=(SELECT Value100 FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK))
```

Ultimately, I need my result set to have 2 columns (`PropertyKey`, and `PropertyValue`). The values in the `PropertyKey` column will be the names of the columns in my table, and the values in the `PropertyValue` column will be the corresponding values.

Is it possible to write this with only one `UNION` if I'm always selecting from the same table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the `UNPIVOT` function you can use it the following way:

```
select PropertyKey, PropertyValue
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  PropertyValue
  for PropertyKey in (Value1, Value2, Value3) -- list other columns here
) unpiv
```

The key piece to keep in mind with an `UNPIVOT` is the datatypes must be the same, so you might have to convert the datatypes:

```
select PropertyKey, PropertyValue
from
(
    select CAST(value1 as varchar(10)), 
         CAST(value1 as varchar(10)), ...
    from yourtable
) src
unpivot
(
  PropertyValue
  for PropertyKey in (Value1, Value2, Value3) -- list other columns here
) unpiv
```

You can even perform this dynamically, which will get the list of columns to transform at run-time:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)    

select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable')
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = 'select PropertyKey, PropertyValue
     from yourtable
     unpivot
     (
        PropertyValue
        for PropertyKey in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u'

exec(@query)
```

If you are stuck, using your current version then I would alter it slightly and use a `UNION ALL` instead of the `UNION`:

```
SELECT 'Value1' as PropertyKey, Value1 PropertyValue
FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Value2' as PropertyKey, Value2 PropertyValue
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does the unpivot example work if I don't have columns named PropertyKey and PropertyValue? Those aren't my actual column names, but I need them returned that way. For example, my resultset will contain a column called PropertyKey, and all the records within will have my actual column names returned as the value in the PropertyKey column. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: @lhan16 The `PropertyKey` will display the names of the columns and the `PropertyValue` will have the value for each column.

Comment: Thanks. The error I'm getting says "The type of column 'Value1' conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list." Is there any sort of casting I need to do if my column types are different?

Comment: @lhan16 yes the datatypes must be the same in order perform the unpivot, see my edit